# "Object not found" error when saving a Google Apps spreadsheet in Box after edit

Tags: google-sheets, collaboration, box.com

The corporate entity that I work for is rolling out Box.com, and since we like the collaborative features of Google Apps, I am experimenting with the Box.com integration with Google Apps.

Using the Box.com web interface, I can open a Google Spreadsheet for editing in Google Apps. I can edit the spreadsheet in the pop-up window and all appears to be fine. Saves appear to be happening fine according to the Google Sheets interface.

When I close the pop up window, the Box.com web interface attempts to save the resulting .gsheet back to Box, but about half the time I get an "Object not found" popup error and then the file becomes greyed out until I refresh the Box.com web interface in my browser. I thought it might be the Box session timing out in the background, but since I can refresh the web UI and I am still logged in, I don't think this is the issue.

[image: Error message shown on the Box.com web UI after closing the Google Sheet]

Thankfully for me, even though the updated file is not saved back to Box, all changes appear to be saved in my personal Google Drive account that I authenticated Box against (although my company security team may not agree that this is useful!).

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to stop it from happening?

Comment: Talking to Box's Customer Success (support?!) team, this appears to be a bug/glitch that they have escalated up to their development team for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with Box customer support, this issue has been resolved. There was a bug somewhere in the integration between Box and Google Docs that I believe both companies had to work to resolve. But resolved it now is.